# How to disable toast notifications in window 8.1 desktop

Tags: notifications, windows-8.1, toast

Now, we are developing a window application for play video like TV.

But When it's running full screen, we must block all window notifications.
so i found many ways to disable notifications.

- http://www.maketecheasier.com/disable-toast-notifications-in-windows-8/

But we can't use this way, because it's for only Window App Store Applications.
We want to block all Notifications.

- connected USB noti, window update noti, etc.

In addition, Our application has property of the Topmost(base on .net C#). 
But it can't Blocked.

is it possible to use the user32.dll??

How to solve it, anyway is ok.

sorry for my poor English. Thanks.